# Share element between recyclerview and toolbar through fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-transitions

I have a weird behavior with share elements and I don't know if it comes from a mistunderstanding of share element or a bad implementation. 
I looked up on Google and no one seems to suffer from the problem I have.

Let me explain. I have two **Fragments**, Fragment *A* is containing a **RecyclerView**, Fragment *B* is a detailed view of recyclerview items. Both have a custom toolbar containing a **TextView**.

I wanted to share the textview of recyclerview items in *A* to the toolbar textview of *B*. Currently, the enter share element transition **is working** (*A*-->*B*) but it does not work in the other way (*A*<--*B*).

During the return transition, the toolbar textview of *B* stays in the toolbar and disappears with the *B* return transition.
But the share element transition works and another textview appears from the top of the recyclerview of *A* and does its job.

There it is the problem. After onBackPressed, the toolbar textview is not shared anymore and a copy of this toolbar textview is made and animated (only in the recyclerview, it doesn't come from the toolbar) instead of share the *B* toolbar textview to *A* recyclerview item

I don't get where is the problem. Transition names are good otherwise animations couldn't work. Any idea? (I am coding under Kotlin)

**FragmentActivity**

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1){
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

**Fragment A Adapter ViewHolder**

```
class AnimationRecyclerViewHolder(val view: View, val listener: AnimationRecyclerCallBack) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val text: TextView = view.animation_recycler_text

    fun bind(data: AnimationRecyclerData) {
        text.text = data.description
        text.transitionName = "textTransitionName$layoutPosition"
        view.setOnClickListener {
            listener.callback(data, view)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment A**

```
override fun callback(data: AnimationRecyclerData, view: View) {
    val frag = AnimationPageFragment.newInstance(data.type, this)
    val transac =  activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transac.shareText(view.animation_recycler_text, context!!, this, frag)
    transac.replace(activity!!.fragContainerCatalogue.id, frag).addToBackStack(null).commit()
}
```

**shareText method**

```
fun FragmentTransaction.shareText(textview: TextView, context: Context, currentFrag: AbstractAnimationFragment, nextFrag: AbstractAnimationFragment) : FragmentTransaction {

    val sharedTransitionName = textview.transitionName
    val bundle = nextFrag.arguments ?: Bundle()

    bundle.putString("sharedTransitionKey", sharedTransitionName)
    bundle.putString("nextTitle", textview.text.toString())
    nextFrag.arguments = bundle
    nextFrag.enterTransition = Fade()
    nextFrag.sharedElementEnterTransition = nextFrag.createShareTransition(sharedTransitionName, currentFrag.context!!)

    currentFrag.activity!!.window.sharedElementsUseOverlay = false
    return this.addSharedElement(textview, sharedTransitionName)
}
```

**Fragment B**

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animation_page_fragment_content, container, false)

    toolbar = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.toolbarShared)
    titleToolbar = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.toolbarTitleShared)

    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    titleToolbar.textSize = 25f
    titleToolbar.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)

    val bundle = this.arguments ?: Bundle()
    val transitionName = bundle.getString("sharedTransitionKey")
    val titleName = bundle.getString("nextTitle")
    titleToolbar.text = titleName
    titleToolbar.transitionName = transitionName
    activity!!.window.sharedElementsUseOverlay = true

    sharedElementEnterTransition = createShareTransition(titleToolbar.transitionName, context!!)

    return rootView
}
```

Comment: Posting some code might help us to figure out where the problem is.. Please show how you implemented transitions.

Comment: Looks like you are only setting a sharedElementEnterTransition - are you missing a sharedElementReturnTransition? This specifies how the view moves back when user hits the back button.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment),  If no value is set to sharedElementReturnTransition, the default will be to use the same value as setSharedElementEnterTransition(Object)

Comment: True. Only thing I can think of then is 1) ensure both your fragments are 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' and/or 2) popBackStackImmediate() might be cancelling your transition animations, and you could try with just popBackStack() (I can't find any documentation on this, though)

Comment: I was using popBackStack() at first but you know when something weird happened and you are hopeless, you try stupid changes like popBackStackImmediate but nothing changes. When I was coding my animation, I used to read that https://github.com/alexjlockwood/custom-lollipop-transitions because the only difference is using a toolbar and perhaps this is the origin of the issue.

Comment: I tried a shareElement directly with a textview and not a recyclerview, it is working. So the issue is not coming from the toolbar. Maybe recyclerview ? I'm still finding out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution.

The issue was indeed related to my **RecyclerView**. 
I never said that my recyclerview was also animated when it is appearing. 
I had an enter animation when the recyclerview appears and an animation when user is scrolling. I disabled both and it worked properly.
Now, I just have to find a way to disable RecyclerView animations on return and everything will be okay.

Thanks for those who read me and tried to help me.

The code I used to solve my issue :

```
frag.setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {
        override fun onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableList<View>?, sharedElementSnapshots: MutableList<View>?) {
            super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots)
            viewAdapter.mApplyAnim = true
        }
})
```